# OpenGL ES 2.0: How do I customize the convolution kernel?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to blur bitmap with some custom shape, like heart/circle or more shape.
box blur or gaussian blur kernel like this(below is box):

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,1]
[1,1,1]
```

I want kernel is like below bitmap, black is 1, white is 0, then use it to blur.

How do I make the kernel of blur to heart shape? In fact, I already know how to make polygons([Efficiently Simulating the Bokeh of Polygonal Apertures
in a Post-Process Depth of Field Shader](https://dipaola.org/art/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/cgf2012.pdf)), but I don't know how to customize the irregular shapes (circles, hearts, moons, and all sorts of weird shapes).
[image]